# java.lang.illegalstateException:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

i got error java.lang.illegalstateException:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 42 when Call API with retrofit, here is my code :

**Here is my interface :**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("myCollection")
Call<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>> getMyCollection(
        @Field("caller_id") String caller_id
);
```

Here is for Call :

```
public class UploadVideoToneActivity extends BaseActivity{
List<MyCollection> collection = new ArrayList<>();

 private void loadCollection() {

    ContactItem callerID = SessionManager.getProfile(this);
    Call<APIResponse<MyCollection>> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getMyCollection(callerID.caller_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse<MyCollection>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<MyCollection>> call, Response<APIResponse<MyCollection>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()) {
                List<MyCollection> data = (List<MyCollection>) response.body().data;
                if (data != null) {
                    collection.clear();
                    collection.addAll(data);
                    rvCollection.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadVideoToneActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<MyCollection>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(UploadVideoToneActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is The format JSON response from API,
Here is The format JSON response from API,

```
{
 "code": 200,
 "error_message": null,
 "data": [
    [
        {
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "003",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Angkat sekarang juga",
            "source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic":  "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 14:17:10",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "002",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Mas Ganteng Angkat Dong",
            "source_content":"source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic":  "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic":"source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic":  "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 15:52:40",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        }
     ]
    ]
   }
```

And here is MyCollection class :

```
public class MyCollection implements Parcelable {
@SerializedName("content_id")
@Expose
public String content_id;
@SerializedName("alias")
@Expose
public String alias ;
@SerializedName("judul")
@Expose
public String judul;
@SerializedName("source_content")
@Expose
public String source_content;
@SerializedName("thumb_pic")
@Expose
public String thumb_pic;
@SerializedName("sub_start")
@Expose
public String sub_start ;
@SerializedName("sub_end")
@Expose
public String sub_end ;



protected MyCollection(Parcel in) {
    content_id = in.readString();
    alias = in.readString();
    judul = in.readString();
    source_content = in.readString();
    thumb_pic = in.readString();
    sub_start = in.readString();
    sub_end = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<MyCollection> CREATOR = new Creator<MyCollection>() {
    @Override
    public MyCollection createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyCollection(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MyCollection[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyCollection[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(content_id);
    parcel.writeString(alias);
    parcel.writeString(judul);
    parcel.writeString(source_content);
    parcel.writeString(thumb_pic);
    parcel.writeString(sub_start);
    parcel.writeString(sub_end);
}
}
```

Comment: Show your MyCollection Class

Comment: Show your ApiResponse<MyCollection> class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all json you provided was incorrect :

This is correct json :

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "error_message": null,
    "data": [{
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "003",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Angkat sekarang juga",
            "source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 14:17:10",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "002",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Mas Ganteng Angkat Dong",
            "source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 15:52:40",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Later for your response class use this as response class:

```
public class MyResponseClass
{
    private String error_message;

    private ArrayList<Data> data;

    private String code;

    public String getError_message ()
    {
        return error_message;
    }

    public void setError_message (String error_message)
    {
        this.error_message = error_message;
    }

    public  ArrayList<Data> getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData ( ArrayList<Data> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getCode ()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode (String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [error_message = "+error_message+", data = "+data+", code = "+code+"]";
    }
}
```

Later use this MyResponseData as your retrofit data parser :

```
ContactItem callerID = SessionManager.getProfile(this);
    Call<MyResponseData> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getMyCollection(callerID.caller_id);
```

and in your onResponse :

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyResponseData> call, Response<MyResponseData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()) {
                //here collection will be arraylist of MyCollection class
                    collection.clear();
                    collection.addAll(response.body().getData());
                    rvCollection.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadVideoToneActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Test it and make minor changes if needed

Comment: thanks ABDevelopers ,
so "data": [
    [
double array is cannot be applied?

Comment: No it is invalida json first of all

Comment: Inside array you can have multiple objects [{},{}] and if you want nested arrays than [ { [ { } ] },{ [ { } ] } ]

Comment: how if my json like this
    "data": [
                { 
                  [
                     {  
                       now i can't get data inside here (in 2nd array)
                     }
                  ]
                }
            ]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are getting response in 'JSONArray' and you are trying to receive in `JSONObject`.

You should use 'List' as return type of `getMyCollection(callerID.caller_id)` method. Then implement the method.

In `onResponse` method you have to get list like below

```
 List<MyCollection> data = (List<MyCollection>) response.body()
```

**Update**

You can visit here (http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

put your `JSON` response and press Submit. You will get Pojo class structure.

Comment: Thanks Asish, i allready change my code in onResponse, but still got same error.. :(
do you have another solution?

Comment: The 'JSON' response you provided is not valid, please share exact response.

Comment: please check Json above, i already update with the new one.. :)

Comment: @aqsa you previous code was correct. Just add ApiResponse<MyCollection> class

Answer (score 1):

Try changing from `APIResponse<MyCollection>` to `APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>`

So the code becomes:

```
public class UploadVideoToneActivity extends BaseActivity{
List<MyCollection> collection = new ArrayList<>();

 private void loadCollection() {

    ContactItem callerID = SessionManager.getProfile(this);
    Call<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getMyCollection(callerID.caller_id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>> call, Response<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()) {
                List<MyCollection> data = (List<MyCollection>) response.body().data;
                if (data != null) {
                    collection.clear();
                    collection.addAll(data);
                    rvCollection.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadVideoToneActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<List<MyCollection>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(UploadVideoToneActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Also update your Json(part) to:

```
"data": [{
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "003",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Angkat sekarang juga",
            "source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 14:17:10",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "caller_id": "44",
            "content_id": "002",
            "alias": "Eli Sugigi",
            "judul": "Mas Ganteng Angkat Dong",
            "source_content": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "thumb_pic": "http://bla.bla.mp4",
            "sub_start": "2017-12-27 15:52:40",
            "sub_end": "2018-01-03 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how if my json like this
    "data": [
                { 
                  [
                     {  now i can't get data inside here (in 2nd array)}
                  ]
                }

Comment: If you keep your json like: **[ { [ {** then the second array is considered totally different from first and you might have to specify different keys to each `JsonArray` to fetch appropriate data; like **"data": { "key1":[ { } ], "key2" : [ { } ] }**